# Direct connection to Graphql API using full admin IAM credentials for Custom Business Logic

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is there a way to use my own nodejs server and admin IAM credentials to perform graphql queries against an amplify graphql API backend with no restrictions so that I can implement my own business logic in nodeJS instead of using custom resolvers or lambda functions?

I know it is possible using aws-sdk, aws.config.update and AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient, but I would like to be able to work with graphql queries and API.graphql or some other SDK that allows me to query the appsync linked to my amplify environment directly.

Thanks.